# Server.Transfer not tranfer some urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.transfer

i use server.transfer at the begining it works perfectly. but then i add another language to my site and i try to do it but it fails with the new language

my code is below

```
   if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("/tr/"))
   {
         Server.Transfer("tr/" + dt.Rows[0]["SourceURL"].ToString());

    }
    else if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("/en/"))
    {
        Server.Transfer("en/" + dt.Rows[0]["SourceURL"].ToString());

    }
```

the "tr" transfers work superb but en fails it stays on my pagenotfound and not transfer to the destination url. i also check to write the whole url like http://mysite.com/en/test.aspx?k=13 and it also works but when server.transfer it fails

can anybody say why?

thanks

Comment: Does it fail when you use Request.Redirect("") with the same URL?

Comment: no it doesnt fail with the response.redirect() but server.transfer and request.redirect are not same as i know so forexample when i call a page like www.mysite.com/en/home i cant use response.redirect() am i right?

Comment: No, they're not the same, so it's worth reading up on the difference. If I remember it right, the Server.Transfer() is more efficient as the request doesn't get sent all the way back to the requester, it's handled within the server.
Resonse.Redirect() works just like the user had clicked / manually entered the URL. so you should be able to call it on your mysite.com website

Comment: sorry i cant get your comment. sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

I think Response.Redirect will work for in your situation for the website " www.mysite.com/en/home"

It won't be as efficient as Server.Transfer, but should work just as well. I'm not sure why it works with "tr/", but not "en/", this might be due to some issue with relative paths. You could try to include a tilda "~" in front of your URL.

```
      Server.Transfer("~/en/" + dt.Rows[0]["SourceURL"].ToString());
```